# Где найти лицензию на jquery,ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, лицензирование

Можете подсказать где можно найти полный текст лицензии на jquery,ajax? искал в интернете ни нашёл

Comment: Не знаю есть ли она, но оооочень интересно зачем? Если не секрет - расскажите

Comment: https://jquery.org/license/

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц для создания коммерческого ПО